# Finding the particular solution for $y'' - y' = -3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general form of the particular solution for this problem. I originally tried $y_p = A$ but that did not give me the correct answer. Do I have to do something different if the constant on the right side of the equation is negative?

Comment: Associated characteristic polynomial has a root $r_1=0$, try $y_p=Ax$

Comment: Is the characteristic polynomial the same thing as the auxiliary equation?

Comment: @JohnParadise: Yes they are the same thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the characteristic polynomial for the associated homogeneous equation: $$r^2-r=0 \implies r=0,1.$$

Therefore, the complementary solution is: $$y_c(x)=Ae^x+B.$$

To find the particular solution, try a function of the form: $y_p(x)=Cx$. Then, $$y''-y'=-3 \implies C=3.$$

Hence, the general solution to the ODE is: $$y(x)=y_c(x)+y_p(x)=Ae^x+B+3x.$$

**EDIT:** You need to multiply your particular solution by $x$, since constants are already a solution to the DE (as found in the complementary solution).